# Loading and saving large images using UIImageJPEGRepresentation crashes my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiimagepickercontroller

My app can take pictures or select them from the camera roll, the, using `UIImagePicker` I send the picture to a `ViewController` where the user then can crop the image.

The final result is `UITableView` with a name and a thumbnail and every row leads to the full sized picture. The thumbnails are the original picture in a different scale.

This is how I save my picture after the crop:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_justNowImage.image, 0.1) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:NO];
```

This is how I open it to a thumbnail or to full size.

```
_imageInPocket.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:jpgPath];
```

If I crop small pictures everything is working fine but I try to crop a big picture (over 2 MB) the app will crash, probably du to lack of memory.

My project is using ARC. Do I still need to release the images from the memory somehow?
Should i create small versions of the images and use them as thumbnails instead of loading all the original pictures in the `UITableView` and change their scale to fit the `Cell` ?

Comment: So your code works in principle but you have problems with a big image? Is it one image or a number of big images that you are dealing with? I sounds like a number of them.

Comment: With ARC you are still in charge with managing your objects properly so that the ARC can release what you do not need. That means that you should set references to objects to nil. You can still overwrite (but not call) the dealloc method of all objects with stron relations so that you nillify them.

Comment: My code works great if I use pictures with resolution lower than 500x500 approximately. The second I use a big picture (the size that iPhone 4 outputs) my app turns slow and will crash after a click or two.

Comment: As there are two questions in your question :) ... Yes, it does save memory when you creat thumbnails and deal with those thumbnails whereever you just need thumbnails. Plus, as said, "release" them. If you display them in a table then do not fill an array of images just to have them handy in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Just load them when required (unlesst that leads to the UI freezing) and store references to it only within the UIImageViews in the cells. Leave caching to the system.

Comment: A final one as I see that you compress the images with factor 0.1. That corresponds to 10% in the usual percentage measure of jpeg quality. You may do so because you aim to save memory. This link may be interesting. http://www.fotocommunity.de/pc/pc/extra/egallery/display/29596438 It goes into my portfolio at fotocommuntiy, which is some sort of German flickr. There is a series of images. Follow the image-links unter the actual image to the next one. It compares JPEG compression from 98% to 10%. You see the sizes and the jpeg artefacts that result of the compression.

Comment: When should I set the objects to `nil`? When I leave the `ViewController` I should set all the image objects to `nil`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You should check with Instruments where your memory usage is...

Comment: Yes, Instruments can give you a hint on where the memory is consumed and based on that you can re-structure your code in order to reduce the amount of memory required at a time. In general you shoudl set references to nil as soon as you do not need the reference any more. When working with UITablViews familiarize yourself with the reusage concept of reusabe cells and then do not work aganinst that concept by keeping references to memory consuming objects which may not be visible. Plus, work with thumbnails wherever suitable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. With Instruments I can see that the biggest memory usage is when I'm saving the picture to the iphone using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Sometimes , if the picture is large, the app will crash in the saving process so there's not really something I can set to nil at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should load the data and convert it to an image using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your URL"];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest
    requestWithURL: url
    cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
    timeoutInterval: 60.0
];
```

When you use this method, you will get your image in packets.
After this you should call and gather all packets

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [imageData appendData:data];
}
```

After this you need to convert the data into an image and close the connection

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
  imageView.image = image;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```